# « Deviner » sans avoir raison

Tags: vocabulaire

En anglais nord-américain, « guess » veut souvent dire « supposer ». Je viens de demander à ma mère ce que contenait une certaine tartelette et j'ai reçu comme réponse :

> We guessed it was peach.

Or on ne les avait pas essayées à ce stade ; j'étais sur le point de vérifier la supposition.

Mais si je disais en français :

> On a deviné que c'était aux pêches.

À mon sens cela signifie qu'on a fini par savoir la nature de la garniture. [L'article du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/deviner) parle en termes de « connaître, savoir, pénétrer, pressentir », où est caché le sens « arriver à découvrir la vérité ». De la même façon, « je l'ai deviné » veut dire quelque chose comme « je l'ai su ». (Néanmoins, on aura répondu à l'ordre « Devine ! » même si on se trompera ...)

Ai-je raison ? Doit-on dire, par exemple, « supposer, estimer, soupçonner, penser » ici ?

Comment: J'ajouterais le verbe "imaginer", pour moi "J'imagine que c'est aux pêches" veut dire "je pense, mais j'ai la flemme vérifier". D'ailleurs "*I guess*" se traduit assez souvent par "j'imagine". Par contre on dit pas "on imagine".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***« On a deviné que c'était aux pêches »*** peut avoir au moins deux sens :

- Après avoir estimé ou supposé que c'était aux pêches, l'inspection (visuelle, gustative ou autre) a confirmé la supposition.
- Après dégustation, on a tenté d'identifier le fruit, mais l'incertitude fut telle qu'on déclare ultimement que c'était aux pêches, mais en indiquant la persistence du doute à l'aide du verbe *deviner*.

***« Je l'ai deviné »***, de la même manière, pourra indiquer soit :

- Qu'on a réussi à supposer ce qui s'est finalement avéré; ou
- Qu'on a dû recourir à la méthode de la devinette et parvenir à une conclusion via une hypothèse difficile à vérifier avec certitude.

***« Devine »*** pour moi est une invitation (impérative, mais bon!) à se prêter au jeu de tenter de découvrir un fait via des indices subtils, l'intuition ou plus simplement la chance. Les joueurs au casino **tentent** de deviner où tombera la boule sur la roulette, mais le casino peut dans tous les cas les inviter à deviner, sans préjuger de la qualité de leurs prédictions.

Pour la traduction de ***« We guessed it was peach »***, tous les verbes proposés *(estimer, présumer, soupçonner, penser, supposer)* me semblent corrects pour déclarer son opinion avant d'obtenir une réponse définitive et supposée atteignable, liste à laquelle on pourra ajouter *deviner (ou devoir deviner : on a dû deviner que c'était aux pêches)* pour le cas où l'incertitude sera demeurée en dépit de l'inspection et de la consommation du produit.

> - *N'était-ce pas plutôt des abricots ?*
> - *Ça goûtait la pêche, mais pourquoi était-ce si rouge ?*

Lorsque la certitude est obtenue, par contre, l'affirmation qu'on a deviné ne s'utilisera que si la supposition est confirmée (à moins que l'on veuille mentir, naturellement).

Comment: "ça goûtait la pêche"? Ne devrait-on pas dire "ça avait le goût de pêche"?

Comment: @Bebs À confirmer par un Belge mais il me semble que dire *ça goûte (la pêche*) est un belgicisme (influence probable du néerlandais).  Dans l'hexagone on dit *ça a (le) goût (de pêche)*, en omettant de préférence l'article défini.

Comment: @Laure ok merci.

Comment: Ainsi, nous belgicisons au Québec? Heureux de l'apprendre. Influence de la bande dessinée, peut-être?

Comment: À la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2742) on en parle de _goûter qqch._ ou de qqc. qui _goûte bon/mauvais_ ; on y parle aussi de la Belgique et du nord et de l'est de la France et on spécule sur un emploi en ancien français populaire. Au [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/go%C3%BBter/37671) ils ont un emploi en Belgique mais qui est différent, intransitif, pour _être agréable au goût_. Ça pourrait faire l'objet d'une question ?