# How to say "good guess"

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Le mot « guess » me gêne [encore une fois](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26015/deviner-sans-avoir-raison).

Avec mes élèves j'ai souvent occasion de dire « good guess » ou quelque chose du genre pour reconnaître un bon effort malgré une réponse fautive. Parfois je dis clairement par exemple :

> Ton raisonnement est plutôt sensé, mais tu t'es trompé sur ce point-ci.
>
> Je suis content que tu te souviennes de tel ou tel fait qu'on a appris, mais ça ne s'applique pas ici.
>
> L'usage habituel du mot permettrait un tel emploi, mais ce contexte est exceptionnel.
>
> C'est bien, mais tu as oublié de prendre tel ou tel fait en compte.

Mais parfois on ne veut qu'une courte interjection. Comme on a dit dans l'autre fil, je sais que « bien deviné » n'exprime pas ce que je veux vu que ce terme implique une réponse correcte ...

Pour le moment je préfère dire « bonne idée ». Y en a-t-il d'autres moyens de le dire ?

Comment: quelques remarques se tromper "sur" un point, ...content que tu te souviennes (subjonctif) de tel ou tel... OU  content que tu t'en souviennes (subjonctif) usage habituel

Comment: @radouxju Merci !

Comment: La phrase "*Je suis content que ...*" est toujours incorrecte, tu peux pas utiliser "*t'en*" si tu dis "*... te souviennes **de** quelque chose*", *en* sert justement à remplacer ce quelquechose. Et *tel ou tel* ne peut pas s'utiliser tout seul (*tel(le) ou tel(le) chose/concept/notion/...*).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Y'avait une virgule imaginaire après *souviennes* ;) En tout cas, j'ai oublié d'ajouter ma requête habituelle, à savoir qu'on se sente libre à corriger la question si besoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Il y a de l'idée.
>
> Bien tenté !
>
> Belle tentative !
>
> On s'en approche.

Answer (score 7):

***Bien essayé !*** indique que le raisonnement est plutôt bon ou astucieux mais que la proposition est incorrecte, au contraire de ***bonne idée*** qui ne tranche pas sur sa justesse.

Comment: Merci, ça a du sens pour *bien essayé*. Quant à *bonne idée*, le suivre par *mais* n'aurait-il pas l'effet désiré ? Je pense à une phrase que j'ai vue sur Linguee : "Votre idée n'est pas mauvaise, mais etc."

Comment: Ce peut être alors: ***Bonne idée, mais non !***

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais :

> Tu y étais presque !!!
>
> Même joueur, joue encore !

Comment: Lol au 2e choix ! Créatif mais peut-être hors de la portée des plus jeunes apprenants. J'aime la suggestion de "presque" en général.

Answer (score 2):

My Maths teacher used to say: “ ah! Vous chauffez!” Which meant we were closer to the right answer. If some got even closer, he would say “vous brûlez!” Almost guessed or figured out! And if someone got the right answer after that, he’d say: bravo, or exactement, or “c’est la bonne réponse. Because the same exists in English: “you’re getting warmer” etc, your students maybe amused to do it in French. 
It comes from a game that all kids play, in France we call(ed) it “cache tampon”.

Comment: Ça mérite un essai, merci !

Comment: All my teachers *tutoyaient* me so that would be ***tu chauffes !***, ***tu brûles !***.

Comment: Absolutely! I was 16 at the time, so teachers would “vouvoyer”  their students/pupils. Actually, come to think of it, in my school, from secondary, we would not only be vouvoyés, but also often called not by first name, but our family name, a bit like in the army! “Mittard, vous êtes en retard!” Some teachers were less formal, but that was the norm for us (I’m going back to the 1980’s here!). So, definitely a good idea to tutoyer  “Tu chauffes!”, “ou la la, tu brûles!”.